# Page not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made an app in RoR and it's working perfectly locally, but there's only one page that's not working when I upload to Heroku. It's a view that has only this in the code:

```
<h1>Listagem</h1>
<% @items.each do |item| %>
<%= link_to item.materia, public_path(item) %>
<% end %>
<br />
```

I noticed that if I remove the public_path(item) the page works, so, is there any alternative to this?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

THe only thing that sticks out to me is that you may have misspelled material in

```
<%= link_to item.materia, public_path(item) %>
```

this would throw an exception.  You might want to [check your logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) as well